# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project) could not find specified instance of Visual Studio

Tags: flutter

I can't run my flutter windows application after changing the Visual Studio installation. I get this errors after running the flutter windows project:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
Building Windows application...
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  Generator

    Visual Studio 17 2022

  could not find specified instance of Visual Studio:

    X:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Preview


Exception: Unable to generate build files
```

I had  Visual Studio 2022 Preview version, but for some reason I removed it and now I have Visual Studio 2022 installed (not the Preview version). and now I can not run the flutter windows project anymore.

This is the output of flutter doctor and all necessary components are installed:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3803], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted. To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 17.8.4)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the problem:

- delete the build folder
- invalidate caches and restart
- and finally run `flutter clean` in terminal. then run the project.

I think the flutter clean is enough but I did does actions before:)